# Karma - Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'scss'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, karma-runner

I have a module which I want to write a test for. I use webpack to transpile it because I'm writing it in ES6.

The file (app.js) starts like this:

```
import template from './app.html'; // pulls in the template for this component
import './app.scss'; // pulls in the styles for this component
```

But when I run the test, I get an error that app.scss is not found

```
ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'scss' in /Users/.../src
 @ ./src/app.js 11:0-21
13 05 2016 10:38:52.276:INFO [..browserinfo..]: Connected on socket /#KYFiNbOR-7lqgc9qAAAA with id 63011795
(browser) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./app.scss"
  at /Users/.../spec.bundle.js:34081 <- webpack:///src/app.js:4:0

Finished in 0.241 secs / 0 s
```

The test starts like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import header from './app.js'; // error occurs here cause .scss file is not recognized

describe('my module', () => {
  let $rootScope, makeController;
  // testing stuff
});
```

My karma.conf.js file includes this:

```
webpack: {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js/, exclude: [/app\/lib/, /node_modules/], loader: 'babel' },
      { test: /\.html/, loader: 'raw' },
      { test: /\.scss/, loader: 'style!css!scss' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I get karma/webpack to read the scss file correctly and run my tests?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a typo:

`scss` should have been `sass`

```
webpack: {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      ...,
      { test: /\.scss/, loader: 'style!css!sass' },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```